# 80s movie with strange, blue, clay-like dog

Tags: story-identification

I remember a movie from the 80s...could have been a comedy. In any case, it featured a spotted blue, almost clay-like dog. Breed looked somewhat like a beagle. It wasn't a claymation film though. The people in it were real actors but the dog must have been mechanical? Anyways, the dog was made to look semi-real. I don't know if the dog played a major role in the film or not.

I don't remember anything about the plot. It was a B-movie. I think there may have been other creatures/animals that looked similar in texture and aesthetic to the dog.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE, is there any more info you can provide? Take a look at [this checklist](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if it'll jog any more memories.

Answer (score -2):

Blue hot dogs were a thing in the BBC version of The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Certainly B-movie quality back then.

Comment: This question is about _dogs_, the animal, not _hot dogs_, the food.